# datagridview button column Winforms

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, datagridview

I have a button column on a `DataGridView` and I am trying to handle a `Button.Click` event but nothing happens when I click a button. Any help?

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.ColumnIndex.ToString());
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 5)
    {
        MessageBox.Show((e.RowIndex + 1) + "  Row  " + (e.ColumnIndex + 1) + "  Column button clicked ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @pikk, do you mean that the event doesn't fire at all?

Comment: Exactly, when i click the button nothing happens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried your sample and it works. Did you really bind the event to your `DataGridView` ?

Please check the `InitializeComponent()` Method in your `<YourFormName>.Designer.cs` class.
Did it really has

```
this.dataGridView1.CellClick += 
  new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventHandler(this.dataGridView1_CellClick);
```

and you don't remove the handler at another place in code ?

The DataGridViewButtonColumn MSDN page has this to say:

> To respond to user button clicks, handle the DataGridView.CellClick or DataGridView.CellContentClick event. In the event handler, you can use the DataGridViewCellEventArgs.ColumnIndex property to determine whether the click occurred in the button column. You can use the DataGridViewCellEventArgs.RowIndex property to determine whether the click occurred in a button cell and not on the column header.

Answer (score 1):

Let me get/clarify that you have button on each row of datagridview in c# windows forms.
So in order to get button click event of datagridview i show you a sample c# code which worked fine for me! Given below is my c# code of button click event of datagridview which worked fine:

```
private void dgTasks_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        var button = (DataGridView)sender;
        if (button.Columns[6] is DataGridViewColumn && e.RowIndex >= 0)
        {
       MessageBox.Show("You have clicked Cancel button of a row of datagridview ", "Task", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information); 
        }
        }
```

Where **dgTasks** is name of my datagridview in c# winforms. **button.Columns[6]** is column number of my datagridview where i have button column named:**btnCancel**,header text:**CANCEL** and text:**Cancel**.
This is just a sample! Hope you find it useful.!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your event hasn't registered correctly.  To check, from the Designer, highlight the `DataGridView` control and select `Properties`, under `Events` check if the `CellClick` event has an entry, if not there should be a drop down available that should list your event - select it and this should solve your problem.