# Adding custom button to gridview in C#.net

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

IDE: Microsoft Visual Studio
Platform: C#.net

Hi,
  I am trying to add a custom button with image for a cell of gridview in c#.net, but not successful in achieving that. Any suggestions?

Comment: No i want to add a button with a background image ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it by two ways in gridview. 
1 without css

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Test">
     <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:Button runat="server" ID="test" Text="upload" Style="background-color: green"/>
     </ItemTemplate>
     <FooterStyle />
     <HeaderStyle />
     <ItemStyle Width="30%" />
</asp:TemplateField>
```

2nd way, same code but replace the style attribute with CssClass="buttonBackground"

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Test">
     <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:Button runat="server" ID="test" Text="upload" CssClass="buttonBackground"/>
     </ItemTemplate>
     <FooterStyle />
     <HeaderStyle />
     <ItemStyle Width="30%" />
</asp:TemplateField>
```

#### CSS

```
.buttonBackground
{
    background-image: url(../Images/backgroundImage.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

Comment: Check the question tags. Winforms != ASP

Comment: The you should try this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085930/add-button-column-in-a-databound-datagridview)

Comment: Also you should check this if your asking about winforms [Link 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10434296/add-buttons-to-datagridview-in-windows-form)

Comment: I am sorry but the link you provided is not helpful for getting a button with background image...